# Is there a known PHP (binary setup) extension that causes httpd to hang on Windows?

Tags: php, windows, apache2, installation, apache

I've encountered this issue before while trying to install PHP5 on multiple versions of Windows. Basically, httpd won't start with PHP's default extensions; I installed it w/o extensions and it works perfectly fine. I know it's an issue w/ PHP, but I don't really know what if I'm missing a package or need to change something php.ini to resolve it.

Comment: what does your httpd log tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit was Sybase extension; I dunno, there could be an issue with Windows, PHP5, Apache2.2, and this extension. Regardless, problem solved.